# Unable to play audio files using Python libraries

Tags: python, audio, libraries

Description:

I am trying to play audio files using Python libraries such as playsound, pygame, and pyaudio, but I'm not able to hear any sound. I have tried running the following code using all three libraries:

Here's the example with play sound below. It's as simple as that.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("output.mp3")
```

There are no error messages displayed, but I'm still not able to hear any sound. I have checked that the volume is turned up on my device, and I have tested the same audio file I can play it with no issues inside VScode itself by pressing the play button.
The path is correct. I already tried inserting the full path but it's still not working.
Until yesterday I was getting no problems at all. today I tried to run the same code and it was not working.
I tried to run the same code on another computer and I get the same issue.

I'm running Python version 3.11 on Windows 10 Pro. Is there something else I need to do to get these libraries to play audio files correctly?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.